# How do I get for loop to repeat for input number of lines?

Tags: c++, for-loop

The program below will repeat the width, but I also want in to repeat for the height input too.

```
 int main () 
 {

 int height;
 int width;
 int count;
 int hcount;
 string character;

 cout << "input width" << endl;
 cin >> width;
 cout << "input height" << endl;
 cin >> height;
 cout << "input character" << endl;
 cin >> character;

      for (hcount = 0; hcount < height; hcount++);
     {
     for (count = 0 ; count < width; count++) 
     cout << character;
     cout << endl;
     }
```

Do I need add another for loop? I cant figure out how to make it repeat. I've tried adding another for loop but changed the order of height and width:

```
          for (count = count < width; count++)
              { (count = count < height; hcount++)
                cout < character;
                cout << endl;
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 2):

A `for` loop operates on the single statement that follows it so

```
for (hcount = 0; hcount < height; hcount++);
```

is equivalent to

```
for (hcount = 0; hcount < height; hcount++)
    ;
```

so your first loop does nothing.  If you remove the trailing semi-colon

```
for (hcount = 0; hcount < height; hcount++)
```

you'll get the nested loops you want.

Note also that

```
for (count = 0 ; count < width; count++) 
    cout << character;
    cout << endl;
```

is actually

```
for (count = 0 ; count < width; count++) 
    cout << character;
cout << endl;
```

If you want both lines to execute for the inner loop, you need to place them inside braces `{}`

```
for (hcount = 0; hcount < height; hcount++) {
    for (count = 0 ; count < width; count++) {
        cout << character;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the semicolon is the only syntactic error, the second "problem" is likely intentional, printing a new line after each inner loop terminates.

Comment: @DerFlatulator The behaviour might well be intentional but, given the indentation, it seemed worth pointing out this additional potential issue.

Comment: Could be worth posting the final code to demonstrate how it should be indented. 
`for (hcount = 0; hcount < height; hcount++) {[\n\t]for (count = 0 ; count < width; count++)[\n\t\t]cout << character;[\n\t]cout << endl;[\n]}`